# Characters of sets of representations closed under tensor product

Tags: rt.representation-theory, characters

Let $R$ denote the set of all irreducible representations of a group $G$ over a complex vector space. Let $U \subset R$ denote a subset of representations which is closed under tensor product (i.e., if $\rho$, $\mu \in U$, then $\rho \otimes \mu = \oplus_{i} \nu_i$ with each $\nu_i \in U$). For $g \in G$, let $\chi_\rho(g) =$ Tr$\rho(g)$ denote the character given by the trace of $g$ in the $\rho$ representation.

Is the following statement true: $U$ is a ***proper*** subset of $R$ if and only if there exists some $g \neq 1 \in G$ such that $\chi_{\rho}(g) = \chi_\rho(1)$ for all $\rho \in U$? Here $\chi_\rho(1):=$ Tr$\rho(1)$ is the trace of the identity element $1 \in G$ in the $\rho$ representation.

I am quite sure this statement is true for $G$ a finite group, and I am especially interested to know if it also holds true for $G$ a Lie group.

Comment: The first question is whether such proper subsets closed under tensor products exist at all. For SU(2) one can use Clebsch-Gordan to see that the only such proper subset is the one consisting of all odd-dimensional irreducible reps. For this set, however, I wouldn‘t see why your claim should be true for some g.

Comment: The claim is true for SU(2). The only proper subset closed under tensor products is indeed the one consisting of all odd-dimensional irreducible reps, and the element g is given by -1, the nontrivial element in the Z2 center of SU(2).

Comment: Your claim is indeed true for finite groups. By a theorem of Blichfeldt/Burnside, it follows, if there is no such $g$, that any irreducible character $\mu$ of $G$ occurs as a constituent of some power of $\sum_{\chi \in U}\chi$, and then the assumed properties of $U$ force $\chi \in U$.